# Remove the middle n characters from lines in Bash

Tags: bash, unix, sed, cut

I am trying to cut out the middle of each line in a file. All the lines are like this:

```
79.472850   97 SILENCE
```

and I need to end up with:

```
79.472850 SILENCE
```

As each line has the undesired portion starting at character ten and ending at character 14, 
I was trying to use sed in this way:

`sed "s/\(.\{9\}\).\{6\}//"` but I just end up with everything after character 14. The numbers following the tab space change in every file. What can I do to make sed just cut out the tab and two digits?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per your input and expected output, this can be a way:

```
$ echo "79.472850   97 SILENCE" | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f1,3
79.472850 SILENCE
```

- `tr -s " "` deletes repeated spaces.
- `cut -d" " -f1,3` prints 1st and 3rd field based on splitting by spaces.

With `sed`:

```
$ sed 's#\([^ ]*\)[ ]*\([^ ]*\)[ ]*\([^ ]*\)#\1 \3#g' <<< "79.472850   97 SILENCE"
79.472850 SILENCE
```

Comment: Accepted because of the explanation of how this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

No need to call external programs like `sed` or `cut`, or other languages like `awk`, **bash** can do it for you:

```
var="79.472850   97 SILENCE"
echo ${var:0:9}${var:14}
79.472850 SILENCE
```

`${var:0:9}` copies 9 characters starting at position 0 (start of text).

`${var:14}` copies from character position 14 to the end of text.

Alternatively, if it is space-delimited fields you need:

```
read one two three <<< "$var"
echo "$one $three"
79.472850 SILENCE
```

Again, that uses pure bash.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you need the first and the third *fields* from the input:

```
$ echo "79.472850   97 SILENCE" | awk '{print $1, $3}'
79.472850 SILENCE
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an awk solution that works even if you have spaces in your third column :

```
awk '{$2=""; print}' file
```

Where `$2=""` empties the second column and
`print` outputs all columns.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to extract exactly like what you described with sed:

```
kent$  echo "79.472850 97 SILENCE"|sed -r 's/(^.{9})(.{4})(.*)/\1 \3/'
79.472850 SILENCE
```

if you want to extract the 1st and 3rd/last columns, from your space separated input, you could use awk: `awk '$2="";7'`

```
kent$  echo "79.472850 97 SILENCE"|awk '$2="";7'
79.472850  SILENCE
```

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern to remove/replace is know, then it can be replaced (with null) using pure Bash:

```bash
VAR="79.472850   97 SILENCE"
echo "${VAR/   97}"
79.472850 SILENCE
```